# copy/archive object in database - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i would like make copy if i add and edit News.

```
class News extends BaseNews
{
    public function postSave(){

        $copy = new CopyNews($this);
        $copy->save();
    }

    public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
    {
      return parent::save($conn);  
    }
}
```

but i have error:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of News::postSave() should be compatible
>   with that of Doctrine_Record::postSave() in ...

How can i make this?

Answer (score 1):

All pre- and post- methods receive $event as a parameter. You should rewrite the method as

```
 public function postSave(Doctrine_Event $event){
    $copy = new CopyNews($event->getInvoker());
    $copy->save();
 }
```

Comment: further i have error Strict Standards: Declaration of News::postSave() should be compatible with that of Doctrine_Record::postSave() in

Answer (score 1):

All you need is within doctrine

```
$copy = $this->copy()
```

... and it's documentation :

http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/component-overview:record:getting-object-copy

Comment: Strict Standards: Declaration of News::postSave() should be compatible with that of Doctrine_Record::postSave() AGAIN

Comment: Maybe, but that's a problem of your function definition. This is from Doctrine_Record API documentation: `public function postSave(mixed $event)` (http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_record_listener.html#postSave%28%29) @Darhazer